# Mongoose/Mongo DB Querying collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I have a problem with my node js app using mongoose, indeed each time I query a collection from the database, I get some weird action that occurs.
For example i get the same object returned two times from the database as if they were different, but they have the same data in it and other object from collection are not sent but if I look for them specifically I can see them anyone has already encoutered this situation with mongoose ?

Comment: Please add some code showing how you run your query

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the query is made with mongoose.

```
const getAllTransferts = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let {
            page,
            size,
            clientName,
            senderName,
            start,
            end,
            city,
            moneyTypes,
            hasTakeMoney,
            hasTakeFilter,
        } = req.query;
        //ADD 2 OBJECT THE FIRST ONE IS USED AS QUERY PARAMETER FOR MONGOOSE FUNCTION
        // THE SECOND ONE IS HERE TO PAGINATION SYSTEM AND SEND QUERY STRING TO LINK BUT WITHOUT THE PAGE QUERY TO AVOID BUGS

        let queryObj = {};

        if (city && city !== 'Tous') {
            queryObj.city = city;
        }
        if (hasTakeFilter !== 'false') {
            if (hasTakeMoney) {
                queryObj.hasTakeMoney = hasTakeMoney === 'true' ? true : false;
            }
        }
        if (clientName) {
            queryObj.clientName = { $regex: clientName, $options: 'i' };
        }
        if (senderName && senderName !== 'Tous') {
            queryObj.senderName = { $regex: senderName, $options: 'i' };
        }
        if (moneyTypes && moneyTypes !== 'Tous') {
            queryObj.moneyTypes = moneyTypes;
        }

        const startOfMonth = new Date(
            moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        );
        let endOfMonth = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        const endCurrMonthY = Number(endOfMonth.split('-')[0]);
        const endCurrMonthM = Number(endOfMonth.split('-')[1]) - 1;
        const endCurrMonthD = Number(endOfMonth.split('-')[2]);

        endOfMonth = new Date(
            endCurrMonthY,
            endCurrMonthM,
            endCurrMonthD,
            25,
            59,
            59,
            999
        );

        const date = {};

        if (start || end) {
            const endYear = Number(end.split('-')[0]);
            const endMonth = Number(end.split('-')[1]) - 1;
            const endDay = Number(end.split('-')[2]);
            date.start = new Date(start);
            date.end = new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 25, 59, 59, 999);
        }

        if (start) queryObj.date = { $gte: date.start };
        if (end) queryObj.date = { $lte: date.end };

        if (start && end) {
            queryObj.date = {
                $gte: date.start,
                $lte: date.end,
            };
        }

        page = page ? Number(page) : 1;
        size = size ? Number(size) : 11;

        const limit = size;
        const skip = (page - 1) * size;
        const agent = await Agent.find({});
        const transferts = await Transfert.find({
            date: {
                $gte: startOfMonth,
                $lte: endOfMonth,
            },
            ...queryObj,
        })
            .sort({ date: -1 })
            .limit(limit)
            .skip(skip);
        const count = await Transfert.count({
            date: {
                $gte: startOfMonth,
                $lte: endOfMonth,
            },
            ...queryObj,
        });

        let totalPages = Math.ceil(count / limit);

        let iterator = page - 2 < 1 ? 1 : page - 2;
        let endingLink =
            iterator + 4 <= totalPages
                ? iterator + 4
                : page + (totalPages - page);

        let sum = await Transfert.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    date: {
                        $gte: startOfMonth,
                        $lte: endOfMonth,
                    },
                    ...queryObj,
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    sum: { $sum: '$amountOfMoneyInEuro' },
                },
            },
        ]);

        sum = sum[0] ? sum[0].sum : '';

        res.status(200).json({
            transferts,
            totalPages,
            currentPage: page,
            iterator,
            endingLink,
            agent,
            sum,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
```

To be more explicit the problem is when i get the query of let's say page 1, I get the requested transfert but when I request page 2 the last element of Page 1 is now the first element of Page 2 while it should have been another element.
And when I query for that specific element, this elements is showing.
I hope what I'm saying makes sense.
Sorry if I made lot of mistakes english mistakes, I'm not native